# Logs output different values Locally VS Prod (Server) using Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have the following `onDelete` Cloud Functions in my node js server:

```
export {};
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

try {admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);} catch(e) {console.log(e);}

// MIN AMOUNT OF NAMES BEFORE SENDING A NOTIFICATION
const MIN_USERS_COUNT = 2;

// Callback triggered when event is deleted from the realtime database
exports = module.exports = functions.database.ref('store/{storeId}/storeName').onDelete((change, context) => {

    const storeName = change.val();
    console.log(`The store name is ${storeName}`);

    const storeId = change.ref.parent.key;
    console.log(`Store id is ${storeId}`);

    return getStoreOwner(storeName, storeId);
});

function getStoreOwner(storeName, storeId) {
    return admin.database().ref(`owners/{storeName}/ownerNames`).once("value").then(function(userSnapShot) {
        // The Promise was "fufilled"
        console.log(`number of names are ${userSnapShot.numChildren()}`)
        if (userSnapShot.numChildren() >= MIN_USERS_COUNT) {
            //Do something ...
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log('No names screen will be prompted if there are only 2 names');
            return null;
        }
    },
        // The Promise was rejected.
        function(errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
}
```

After executing the command: `firebase functions:shell`
**I ran the following function locally:**

```
dbNotificationsOnDelete('CoffeeIsLife', {params: {storeId: '01129434'}});
```

And I'm getting the results that I'm looking for as far as output:

*Logs:*
    info: User function triggered, starting execution
    info: The store name is CoffeeIsLife
    info: Store id is 01129434
    info: number of names are 2

**However, when I ran it on prod, the output was different:**  (I triggered it by manually deleting the node from the Firebase Realtime Database).

*Logs:*
    info: User function triggered, starting execution
    info: The store name is CoffeeIsLife
    info: Store id is 01129434
    info: number of names are 0

**PROBLEM:** The number of names is different Locally VS Prod. Can't it be that the deletion in prod is happening before the function gets to reading the number of children, that's why it is returning 0 in prod and it is retrieving the actual value locally?